# Trello status and trello sidebar-ad

Tags: discussion

Every once in a while I get the "we're on trello" ad on the right side, linking to this trello page: https://trello.com/b/h7PINsB9/ask-ubuntu

I've got the feeling it isn't that actively used anymore (Last activity: Sep 28, 2012 at 1:05 am"). It's a bit awkward boasting presence on Trello with that, isn't it?

I suppose we could either try and add some life to Trello, but that might not work, so the other option might be to stop showing that ad?

Comment: Downvoting the ad in the meta question seems a democratic way to kill it...

Comment: @Braiam Just do it™

Comment: It's this post to downvote: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5507/88802

Comment: The Trello community ad has been downvoted below 6 votes. That should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to stop having the ad there. You can't (and shouldn't want to) force a community tool like Trello, and if it isn't working, it isn't working.

It seems that downvoting on this post is the way to show this:  http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5507/88802

Comment: Trello works.  It's just not used.  Voting on the question like two other people already told you to do will fix the problem.  People get touchy about deleting posts.  Just vote your conscience.

Comment: I know trello works. This discussion isn't about that. I asked a question and could see 2 options: 1: either try and use trello more (which doesn't work as far as I'm concerened: _forcing_ doesn't work, the tool can however (I'm a user myself, but clearly not for this site)) 2: delete the ad. As I think this is a legit question, it can have an answer. And it seems you agree with me, so why the downvote? I'd say the answer could be more complete, because the downvote-link isn't in here. I'll add it, but I'm not sure what your comment is supposed to add here?

Comment: (basically: I thought I saw an add that needed some attention, so I opened a meta question about it. sounds legit to me)